# vim : Highlight tab with one color and spaces with another ?

Tags: vim, tabs, spaces

How can I highlight tabs with one color and spaces with another in vim ?

I know how to highlight only tabs or only spaces. And I don't know how to select the colors separately for both spaces and tabs.

Comment: Show us what you already have so that we can save some time.

Comment: Also, if you don't really want highlighting, but just to be able to tell the difference between tabs and spaces, you can use the `list` option. See `:h list`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple solution would be to do something like:

```
:match Error /\t/
:2match Todo / /
```

Where `Error` and `Todo` are highlight groups from `:highlight`.  This is going to take up two of your three matches and will only be temporary.

Theoretically you could use `matchadd()` or a combination of highlight groups and `:syntax match` commands in your .vimrc to make this more permanent but your question doesn't really specify if that's what you want.